# how to use Group By in RDLC Report ( Group data by Date )?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

i have a report that shows Monthly attendace of employee..
Each day has 2 or more than two entries for a employee , 1 when he signin and the other when he leaves
i have to use Group by Days like this,

Note: 
INOUT 1 = TimeIN
INOUT 2 = TimeOut

TID             **ATTENDANCEDATE**                                                      EMPID               **INOUT**

***01 nov 2010***

37219               **2010-11-01 09:01:00.000**                     0000000001  **1**

37109               **2010-11-01 18:02:00.000**                 0000000001              **2**

***02 nov 2010***

37219               **2010-11-01 09:01:00.000**                     0000000001  **1**

37219               **2010-11-01 09:16:00.000**                     0000000001  **1**

37109               **2010-11-01 18:02:00.000**                 0000000001              **2**

i have use =Fields!AttendanceDate.Value in Parent Group and Included Group Header

**The Problem is the report is only showing 1 record in each group..
please tell me how i can do this?**

Answer (score 1):

When you group by the date, it also including the time, so each second will produce a new group.

Try to format the string to exclude the time like:

Format(Fields!ATTENDANCEDATE.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")